# Python: run functions on a schedule without overlapping some execution

Tags: python, cron, scheduled-tasks, apscheduler

I have been using the [schedule](https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler) module to try and schedule functions in my python code but I think my use case exceeded its capability.

At the moment I have 4 functions that I would like to run on a set schedule.
I would like to run function_1 every hour, function_2 and function_3 on alternating hours, and function_4 once a week on its own.

My current job schedule is as follows:

```
schedule.every(1).hours.do(function_1)
schedule.every(2).hours.do(function_2)
schedule.every(3).hours.do(function_3)
schedule.every().monday.do(function_4_setup)

def function_4_setup()
    logger.debug("Clearing Schedule to run function_4 on its own")
    schedule.clear()
    sleep(3600)
    function_4()
    logger.debug("Restarting All Jobs")
    recreate_jobs() # re-adds function 1-3 to schedule
```

The problem is this code will result in function_2 and function_3 running at the same time or immediately after one another after 12 hours 18 hours and 24 hours which I would like to avoid.

To give you an example of the behavior I'm expecting:

- 00:00: function_1 & function_2 runs
- 01:00: function_1 & function_3 runs
- 02:00: function_1 & function_2 runs
- 03:00: function_1 & function_3 runs

... 1 week later...

- 00:00 function_4 runs
- 01:00 function_1 & function_2 runs

I have taken a look at [APScheduler](https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler) but that library also doesn't appear to accommodate my use case. Any advice/help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of scheduling function 2 & 3 separately, I recommend making a function that flip flops the 2 functions and instead run that every hour. For example:

```
boolean = True

def flip_funcs():
    global boolean
    boolean = not boolean
    [function_2, function_3][boolean]()

schedule.every(1).hours.do(flip_funcs)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! While not the most elegant solution this achieves what I asked. Any ideas for how to extend this to flip through more than 2 functions?

Comment: You're welcome. For more than 2, add all the functions into a list and instead of a boolean you can use an int or even a generator to cycle through the execution.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried doing multithreading on that function?
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm
It might be what you're looking for